# Basic form in Wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I need to simply get a search term from a `form` into a variable. I have set up a basic `form` within a template file, that template file is then linked to a page within Wordpress admin. The problem I am getting is that the `form` doesn't submit so I am unable to use the variable. If I remove `get_header();`  from the template then the form will submit but obviously it break wordpress stuff.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" >
    
      <label>
        <input placeholder="Search…" name="qcsearch" type="text">
      </label>  

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

  </ul>
</form>
```

I have tried leaving out the action, using the template name which is qccerts.php and using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Here is then what I am trying to do with the output:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){   
  $searchterm = $_POST["qcsearch"];
}else{
  $searchterm = '';
}
```

Its basically a simple search which tells the users if there is a file by the name they search. So I need to populate `$searchterm` so I can use it later down the page.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please share more details - what do you mean by "the form doesn't submit"?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure. I press the submit button and when I echo $searchterm nothing shows. WHen I remove the wp_header it does show

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? If you dump `$_POST`, what  does that contain?

Comment: I just tried print_r($_POST) and var_dump($_POST) and they are empty. Its weird because if I removed wp_header it works, so the form must be working but some Wordpress thing is stoppping it

Comment: You might want to try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute in the `<form>` tag

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine what your exact problem is without a reproducible scenario. For example, without seeing your problem, I'm not sure whether the `form` is really not submitted at all, or submitted, but you did not see it being executed, or there is some Javascript which prevents your form from submitting. There is a possibility that the form is submitted to the wrong action as well.

However, if you intend to keep your search term accross the pages, you could add it into session. Let's imagine these functions:

```
function storeSearchTerm($searchTerm) {
    $_SESSION["searchterm"] = $searchTerm;
}

function getSearchTerm() {
    return isset($_SESSION["searchterm"]) ? $_SESSION["searchterm"] : "";
}
```

By calling these functions you can manage the search term, initializing it via `storeSearchTerm($_POST["qcsearch"])` or something.

As about your actual form, if it does not work, then you can `submit` the form in `Javascript`, such as

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

and make sure that this is triggered either via an `onclick` attribute, or a `click` event listener on the button created via `addEventListener`.

EDIT

It turns out that a class name was not well formed (case-sensitivity issue).

Comment: Hi, I don't need to keep the result across pages. Its only used as a quick tool to show if something is there to proceed with. I will have a look at javascript

Comment: @snookian have you taken a look at the Network tab of your developer tools in the browser? If you click on the submit button, is there a new record in the grid?

Comment: Not sure how to read developer tools but it doesn't seem like any new records appear. Pulling my hair out over this one. Because if I removed  get_header(); or wp_head from inside teh header it works so its ovo something to do with wordpress

Comment: "Not sure how to read developer tools" That's the main problem.If you knew how to read it, then it would be so much easier to detect what the problems are. So, if I were you, I would first learn how to use developer tools very carefully and only then return to the question equipped with this knowledge. You cannot fight a dragon with a string of a straw. You need proper equipment.

Comment: lol...thanks... Turns out the class name was causing an issue so I changed that and it all work.

Comment: @snookian sure thing. I have edited my answer to reflect the new information you have given.